# make new thread for send mail Id in java

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I am working in online application, in which there is facility of creating group. I want facility to send mail to all group user when any activity done in group. like comments , start new discussion etc. But problem is that . if any small activity i send thorusand of mail at run time. it slow the performance.

For that i am thinking to create new independent thread. to send mail which send mail to thousand of user and main thead with out any problem come to group page.

How i will make new thread in class. 
thanks in advances.

for more info visit http://www.rameshsengani.in

Comment: you say it's a "online application" which makes me think it's likely a running in a web-container like tomcat.  if that is indeed the case. spawning your own threads probably isn't a good idea.  I'm not sure i really understand the problem your trying to solve, but you might look into having you emails sent by some job scheduled to run periodically.

Answer (score 3):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // do stuff here
    }
}).start();
```

This is the accepted Java pre-1.5 way. You can take a look at the `java.util.concurrent` package and the [executor framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).